# mocha - Retrieve result of promise test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I want to get the result of promise in `before`

```
describe('unsubscribe', function() {
        var arn;
        this.timeout(10000);
        before(function(done) {
            sns.subscribe('param1', 'param2').then(
                (result) => {
                arn = result;
                done();
            },
            (error) => {
                assert.fail(error);
                done();
            });
        });
        it('("param") => promise returns object', function() {
            const result = sns.unsubscribe(arn);
            expect(result).to.eventually.be.an('object');
        });
    });
```

Similarly, in `after` I want to get result of promise in test

```
describe('subscribe', function() {
        var arn;
        this.timeout(10000);
        it('("param1","param2") => promise returns string', function(done) {
            sns.subscribe('param1', 'param2').then(
                (result) => {
                    arn = result;
                    expect(result).to.be.a('string');
                },
                (error) => {
                    assert.fail(error);
                    done();
                });
        });
        after(function(done) {
            sns.unsubscribe(arn).then(
                (result) => done());
        });
    });
```

Is this code properly written? Is there any better practice? What is the recommended way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every place you want to have Mocha wait for a promise to be resolved you should just return the promise rather than use `done`. So your `before` hook can be simplified to:

```
    before(() => sns.subscribe('param1', 'param2')
        .then((result) => arn = result));
```

This is much more readable than having `done` here and there and having to do anything special for error conditions. If there is an error, the promise will reject and Mocha will catch it and report an error. There's no need to perform your own assertions.

You have a test and an `after` hook that could also be simplified by just returning the promises they use rather than using `done`. And if you test depends on a promise, **remember to return it**. You've forgotten it in one of your tests:

```
it('("param") => promise returns object', function() {
  const result = sns.unsubscribe(arn);
  // You need the return on this next line:
  return expect(result).to.eventually.be.an('object');
});
```

Tip: if you have a test suite in which all tests are asynchronous, you can use the `--async-only` option. It will make Mocha require all tests to call `done` or return a promise and can help catch cases where you forget to return a promise. (Otherwise, such cases are hard to if they don't raise any error.)

Defining a variable in the callback to `describe` and setting it in one of the `before/beforeEach` hooks and checking it in the `after/afterEach` hooks is the standard way to pass data between hooks and tests. Mocha does not offer a special facility for it. So, yes, if you need to pass data which is the result of a promise you need to perform an assignment in `.then` like you do. You may run into examples where people instead of using a variable defined in the `describe` callback will set fields on `this`. Oh, this works but IMO it is brittle. A super simple example: if you set `this.timeout` to record some number meaningful only to your test, then you've overwritten the function that Mocha provides for changing its timeouts. You could use another name that does not clash now but will clash when a new version of Mocha is released.

Comment: Thank you for proper answer. One more question: What about if returned result of a promise in test has many `expect`. When will it be returned?

Comment: `chai-as-promised`'s assertions are promises, so you can chain them as any promise by using `then`. You could have `return expect(result).to.eventually.be.an("object").then(() => expect(otherResult).to.eventually.be.whatever)`